# Why "test user-doc.doc" ==> TESTUS~1.DOC?

Tags: c#, file, double-click

I wrote a c# program and I associated it with file extension like `DOC` in a PC without MS-Office installed. Then, I double-clicked any file which name contains blank characters, my program will be launched to open that file. I used below statement:

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

and then `args[1]` will contain full path file name of that file. Then, I can open it. But the problem now is that if the file name contains blank characters, `args[1]` contains file name different from the real one. As title, if my file is in `e:\tmp3` and file name is `test uesr=doc.doc`, I expected `args[1]` contains

```
"e:\tmp3\test user-doc.doc",
```

but it actually contains

```
"E:\tmp3\TESTUS~1.DOC"
```

Could anyone tell me why and how to resolve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already mentioned these are 8.3 file names. If you need to convert from a short name to a full name then you can easily do this with C#.

```
new FileInfo("E:\tmp3\TESTUS~1.DOC").FullName
```

Going the other way requires a PInvoke call to [`GetShortPathName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364989%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). [Be aware that this doesn't work on all NTFS volumes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2013/10/09/getshortpathname-doesn-t-return-short-path-name.aspx) as short names can be turned off but they are turned on by default for the volume the OS is on.

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int GetShortPathName(String pathName, StringBuilder shortName, int cbShortName);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fullname = args[0];
        var shortPathBuilder = new StringBuilder(fullname.Length);
        GetShortPathName(fullname, shortPathBuilder, shortPathBuilder.Length);
        var shortname = shortPathBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. +1. My answer basically stretched my knowledge of the subject to the limit!

Comment: It works. Thank a lot. This sample codes gave me lots of help.

Comment: David Ewen, Thanks for reminding me. This is the first time I did it. Hope I already did it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You should put double quote marks around the `%1` replacement in the `shell\open\command` registry key. For example:

```
"C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyApp.exe" "%1"
```

rather than

```
"C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyApp.exe" %1
```

If you don't include the double quote marks, Windows detects that filenames with spaces (or other parameter separators) are unlikely to work, and substitutes the short file name. This is for compatibility with 16-bit Windows programs (the `HKCR\shell` key was introduced for Windows 3.1).

Answer (score 1):

They are called [8.3 Filenames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename). Basically, they are an alias for the file in the File Allocation Table that shortens the path to the file.

8.3 refers to "8 characters.. then a dot.. then 3 characters". The three characters are the file extension obviously..

Also, you'll note that `TESTUS~1` is 8 characters in length.

As far as I am aware, there isn't really much you can do to stop Windows from doing this. You could format your disk to be NTFS I think (I don't think NTFS is so aggresive with file "aliasing").

Comment: My program will be run at some other's computers. It seems not a godo idea to format the disk to be NTFS. :)

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with space character (the blank one), as it will consider it
as args[2] i.e. test user-doc.doc will be treated as two args instead of one
due to blank character, so you can use sub string function, with calculating
total number of args as well, then first concatenate all args from args[1] to args[n]
where n is the size of args, this way you can avoid the problem

Comment: args[2] doesn't exist because the args.Length is 2.