# GetCommandLineArgs Returns incorrect path from network location with spaces

Tags: c#

I have a noodle scratcher

I want to grab a filename from the command line argument - the program is invoked using the context menu (right click) and calling, to do this it is added to the registry etc etc.

It works fine on local files on lettered drives, however when I run it against a network address that contains spaces I hit an issue.

i.e. "\\server\test folder\filename.txt"

If there are no spaces it seems to return the correct path. If there are spaces in the directory or filename it turns that component into jibberish.

Example Images:

[Path with spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHL7O.png)
`\\192.168.0.200\Web\1K5SXZ~6\T5MSMN~1.TXT`

[Path without spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dntu8.png)
`\\192.168.0.200\Web\testdirectory\testfile.txt`

Code used:

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

foreach (string a in args)
{
    MessageBox.Show(a);
}
```

Any Thoughts?

Thx
E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because if the executable was called with an argument with spaces you wouldn't be able to differentiate wether it's 2 arguments or one:

`myapp.exe \foo bar\baz`

Could be interpreted as `\foo` and `\bar\baz` (2 arguments, because there's a space) rather than the (intended) `\foo bar\baz`; usually you just surround the path with quotes to prevent this:

`myapp.exe "\foo bar\baz"`

I guess explorer just takes the safe(r) route* and simply uses the [8.3 filename](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename#VFAT_and_Computer-generated_8.3_filenames) which will never contain spaces anyway and, thus, remove the need for quotes.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23148666/215042) for more; if you want the [LFN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_filename) (Long File Name) it's easy to get it back:

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

foreach (string a in args)
{
    MessageBox.Show(new FileInfo(a).FullName);
}
```

---

* Actually; I think maybe explorer does so because it has no way of knowing if it's invoking an "LFN aware" application. But that's just (not well thought-through) speculation on my part.